# Missing datas in components when using fetch() and navigating via nuxt-link in generated static site

Tags: javascript, components, fetch, nuxt.js, generate

I have a question regarding the use of fetch in components.
I'm developing a website using the target: static parameter. I get my datas from DATO using asynData() in pages and fetch() in components. Unfortunately when I generate my site I do have all the datas when I reload each page, but I miss the fetch() ones when I navigate via nuxt-links. All I read on internet is that it's supposed to be working since 2.14 version. Did I misunderstood something?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may need `fetchOnServer: false` in your component if you're using full static.

Comment: Thx @hey_its_jimmy but it doesn't work. When i run npm start, I get a 401 error as if it's still trying to do the request but it now fails. The weird thing is the datas are in the generated payloads, but instead of getting them, it tries to execute the request. Which doesn't make sense to me since I'm in full static mode?